# Windows 10 update deletes the registry Run command

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, windows-update

A user of [my app](https://www.quickaccesspopup.com) reports that the app's auto-start option stored in the Windows registry section HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run is removed each time a Windows 10 update is executed.

Is this normal because I store it in the "CurrentVersion" section? Should I store this value elsewhere or differently to make my Run entry persistent over Windows 10 updates?

Your expert input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure you've setup a test case on your own environment to find out it is not happening normally, right? The user must have something on their system that does this, instead.

Comment: What’s more interesting, why doesn’t your application create the key if it’s missing?

Comment: @ramhound: simply because this setting is an option. If the key is not there, it is normally because the user does not want the app to auto-start.

Comment: @JnLlnd - You can verify the setting is enabled, and create the key if it does not exist, just trying to suggest a solution to the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Startup registry value for current user:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
```

Startup registry value for all users

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
```

Windows update doesn't  delete those registry keys. But windows defender could be. You can check history of windows defender or any other anti virus software of your PC to check that happened.

Comment: I'm using HKEY_CURRENT_USER because this key is a user-based option. Thanks @Razi for confirming that Windows update doesn't delete this registry key normally. I'll ask my user to check this if he can (I do not have access to his machine).